View class com.google.android.material.imageview.ShapeableImageView is an AppCompat widget that can only be used with a Theme.AppCompat theme
So basically  i have an error:
"View class com.google.android.material.imageview.ShapeableImageView is an AppCompat widget that can only be used with a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant)."
This error does not interfere my application, but I would feel more relaxed if this error did not exist in the Logcat. How can I fix it?
I tried to put the compat theme in the manifest file in the parent activity, but its didn't work.
Someone have any solutions??
